# Как сделать, чтобы при генерации изображения сохранялись пропорции?

Tags: gd, изображения, php

Добрый вечер, всем. Делаю интернет-магазин и столкнулся с такой проблемой на главной странице магазина

[image: Интернет-магазин]

Как мне сделать, чтобы при генерации изображения сохранялись пропорции? Использую PHP.

Comment: Сейчас высота и ширина изображения проставлены просто через атрибуты тега img по 250 пикселей.

Comment: Как сжать изображение с помощью PHP до 250 на 250 пикселей, сохраняя пропорции при этом? Использовать буду библиотеку GD. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для определения размеров используйте imagesx и imagesy.

Изменить размер можно с помощью imagecopyresampled.