# как можно в php можно организовать загрузку изображения изменяя размер но сохраняя пропорции

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

На странице у меня размер под изображение 320x300 .Как загружать и сохранять в 320x300 и не терять пропорции чтобы это выглядело красиво на странице.если сейчас посмотреть на сайте  хочуподкрышу.рф изображения выглядят дальновидно не опрятно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/256056/256824 Либо добавьте ваш конкретный код в вопрос.